# group by with max and order

Tags: mysql, group-by, sql-order-by, max

in a table like this:

```
code        code1   code2   code3   code4
FILA841201  123456  481201  654987  NULL
NULL        123456  481201  1234    NULL
NULL        123456  481201  789014  324324
```

I need to get only one line, today use these queries

> CREATE TABLE tmp2 (SELECT max(code) as code, code1, max(code2) as code2, max(code3) as code3, max(code4) as code4 FROM tmp1 WHERE code1 IS NOT NULL group by code1);
>
> CREATE TABLE tmp3 (SELECT max(code) as code, max (code1) as code1, code2, max(code3) as code3, max(code4) as code4 FROM tmp1 WHERE code2 IS NOT NULL group by code2);

ecc... Cycled for all columns

my problem is that if there are different values ​​in a column, I have to give way to the line that has the first column filled.

in this example the code3 I must get out "654987" and not the max (789014).

the result that I should get

```
code        code1   code2   code3   code4
FILA841201  123456  481201  654987  324324
```

thanks for your attention

Comment: There is no such things as a "first row".  Do you have a column that specifies the ordering of the rows?

Comment: Today no, wishing I could create it

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a column that specifies the ordering of the rows, you can do this with correlated subqueries:

```
select (select code from tmp1 where code is not null order by id limit 1) as code,
       (select code1 from tmp1 where code1 is not null order by id limit 1) as code1,
       (select code2 from tmp1 where code2 is not null order by id limit 1) as code2,
       (select code3 from tmp1 where code3 is not null order by id limit 1) as code3,
       (select code4 from tmp1 where code4 is not null order by id limit 1) as code4
```

Comment: in this case if I have different values ​​it will create two rows , I need that I ignore successive values ​​if different ..

Comment: @user2069604 . . . There is no possibility of this query returning more than one row.

Comment: This query has generated a table almost identical to the first , but still did not work , because there is no group by. with the system that I use now step from 95.000 to 18.500 records, but I have the problem that I said before , if any one has the first column is valued, must have the predecenza on others of his own column if they are different

Comment: @user2069604 . . . Have you noted that the query in this answer has no `from` clause.  It cannot return more than one row.